# A way to notify users of important orders

Tags: php, sql-server

We have a custom built API for a customer that places orders with our warehouse. At the moment they are all just standard orders however I have been told they are now going to be doing fast track orders which need to be picked up straight away.

At the moment I just send an email to the relevant people who need to know of the order but have been told this is not enough for this new fast track process. I have though about SMS or maybe an automated outgoing voice call but wondered if anybody else had a better idea?

It needs to be reliable and free or cheap. I was hoping for a network connected device which i could open a socket within PHP and make some sort of alarm go off

Thanks in advance

> EDIT:
>   I understand that this is mainly caused by the inefficiency of the warehouse 
>   team not doing their job properly but management wants to address this 
>   technically to force the team to process these orders

Comment: Attach a gun to a raspberry pi and when the order gos thru, it shoots.

Comment: Why is an email not fast enough? Maybe the relevant people are just to slow to check the emails, usually you get an email notification right away!?

Comment: Emailing orders seems very inefficient. Give people in the warehouse a web interface that shows them which orders to pick, and prioritize fast track orders.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware They also have a web interface but do not check this often enough for the speed of the fast track to go out

Comment: @xander They do not check their emails very often as they are busy packing orders etc but will need to know if a fast track comes in as a priority

Comment: So if they never check anything what can you do? Do they even look at the monitor? If not you need an external device indicating something important, like a red light. :)

Comment: @xander Agreed, and as annoying as it is, it's out of my control so the red light may be a viable option. Looking for any recommendations on how to set this up and not sure why i am getting downvoted for asking a genuine question

Comment: @WillParky93 Love your idea by the way but the warehouse might get messy and they will ask for an automated way to detect if somebody has been shot and clean the blood, call the relevant emergency services etc

Comment: Something like https://www.pagerduty.com seems to do a lot, and easy to integrate. Price is, however, unknown, so probably expensive. There might be others, doing similar thing. Just SMS through a PHP API? https://www.textmagic.com Price seems good.

Answer (score 1):

2 very easy/quick options.

Create an email address that is specifically for fast track order notifications.  Configure the address on a device with very loud speakers, set the mail client on the device to play a really annoying alarm at full volume every time an email is received to that account.

This allows you to utilise what you have in place already (from reading the comments), costs are low, allows workers to easily distinguish priority orders.

Alternatively if you wanted to go down the PHP route.  Create a page that refreshes/polls automatically, each time querying your orders.  When a fast track order is picked up in the results again have the page play a really loud annoying alarm.

I would have placed this in the comments but I don't have enough cred for that yet.

Edit: Just to expand, if you go for the PHP Polling option.  Have it on a dedicated display screen.  I'd also run it via Chrome in Kiosk mode.